# Write values from HTTP put to MySQL Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, ftp

Firstly I am a DB/PHP newb, so learning on the fly here. I understand this may seem quite advanced for a newb but I have all the infrastructure setup on Amazon AWS (I work in networks for a living so that part is easy!).

Basically I have an android app that enables me to export data collected to external sources including FTP, Dropbox, and URL. I have FTP working to an Amazon EC2, but this just dumps the data in a text file on the server which is not what I need. What I really need is to put the data directly into the DB which I am hoping I can do with the URL export option... The app options include adding username/password for URL auth, and each of the variables are separated by an "&", so for example:

http://IP/log?firstname=%FIRST&lastname=%LAST

So, this question is really multi pronged.

Firstly I need to get the data into the database. I am hoping to do this by pointing the app to the db, but I am sure there is some coding I need in between to make this happen which I am clueless about.

Secondly I need the data stripped so I am only putting in for example First name, last name , not all the other bits and bobs.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

#### Edit

These are the fields of my MySQL table:

```
    Timestamp VARCHAR(50),
    Battery VARCHAR(10),
    Temperature VARCHAR(10),
    Latitude VARCHAR(50),
     Longitude VARCHAR(50),
    Speed VARCHAR(50),
    Altitude VARCHAR(50),
    Satellites VARCHAR(50),
    Android_ID VARCHAR(50),
    Android_Serial VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: You started naming PHP and then nohing more. Why you mentioned php? The solution is indeed in php possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code sample on how to go about this.

```
// If this is a put request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    // Change the db_hostname, db_user, db_pass and database
    // values to your own database settings
    $conn = mysqli_connect('db_hostname', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'database');
    $firstName = isset($_REQUEST['firstname']) ? addslashes($_REQUEST['firstname']) : false;
    $lastName = isset($_REQUEST['lastname']) ? addslashes($_REQUEST['lastname']) : false;

    // If both values are given ...
    if (false !== $firstName && false !== $lastName) {
        // Define statement
        $stmt = "INSERT INTO names (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('".$firstName."', '".$lastName."')";

        // Execute query
        mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);
    }
}
```

Create a new file named `log.php` and place this in your webserver root.

The url you will need to `PUT` your requests to:

```
http://IP/log.php?firstname=%FIRST&lastname=%LAST
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I do have a question about where this code is actually placed? I assume I need to put it into its own file or add it to another php file? Thanks again.

Comment: @Adzza Answer has been updated - If you could be so kind as to share your database table, then I can adjust the query to work with your database.

Comment: Awesome Peter. I am still finalising the database table but will report back when its done so we can test this baby out. Thanks again so much!

Comment: Hey Peter here is what I have setup:   Timestamp VARCHAR(50), Battery  VARCHAR(10), Temperature VARCHAR(10), Latitude VARCHAR(50), Longitude VARCHAR(50), Speed VARCHAR(50), Altitude VARCHAR(50), Satellites VARCHAR(50), Android_ID VARCHAR(50), Android_Serial VARCHAR(50));

Comment: @Adzza The table name is missing - side note: Next time, try and add additional information by editing your question.

Comment: Peter, please help this gentleman with the chosen datatypes :P